# Laravel: calculated field used in a query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on a function that allows a user to check if their existing device contacts are using our platform, based on phone numbers.

For privacy and security, we are hashing the user's contact's phone numbers on device (salted with the user's id) before sending to our server.

Server side, we then need to hash our entire contacts table (using the user's id as a salt), which is currently being done in a for loop.

We then check this list against the request list, and return the details for any matches.

However, I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this, something like computing the hash in a calculated field then including the $request->hashes in a "whereIn" clause.

Could someone give me a pointer on the best approach to be taking here?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what privacy and security are you achieving by sending hashed value of contact number?

1. You are hasing the contact in client side(device), that means you are using a key and salt that is available in clinet side already. How can that be a security feature?
2. If you want to search hashed value in database then it's better to save hashed contract number in a column in the first place. So you can directly run where query in database table.

Ideally, if you really concern about user's contact number you should:

1. Encrypt the user's contacts in backend/databse not in frontend.
2. If you need to query for a field in database then you should make a hash valued column that can be matched easily. I mean searchable fields should be hashed so you can run direct query.
3. Nothing to worry about user's contact security in frontend if you are already passing it trhough Secure HTTP(HTTPS).

Even it a common practice in the industry, to pass a submitted plain password via HTTPS when a user submit it in frontend. It shouln't be a concern of privacy or security.

Comment: You have not understood the problem. By hashing the phone numbers client side (using a one way hash), it means that we're not receiving a full list of all the user's contact's phone numbers. This is not the user's own phone number, these are the phone numbers of all their contacts, who have no relationship with us, and haven't given us permission to process their data. This way, we receive only hashes (and never see the actual numbers), and then compare them to our hashes, and return the matches. We consider other people's phone numbers sensitive data, that even we shouldn't have access to!

Comment: Aah I see, sorry for not understanding it. Then I can only see an efficient way can be to have a `hashed_contact` in the table then running where query. So you will always generate that hashed value in the database everytime a user is registered or contact updated.

Comment: The idea is to use a salted hash, as it would be relatively trivial to create a rainbow table for all the phone numbers in the world (there aren't that many!).Therefore, the "hashed column" on the server changes depending on the user making the request, and therefore needs to be computed during the request, not when the user is created or updates their phone number. As our user database grows, this call is going to become more expensive, hence looking for the most efficient way to compute the hashes.